# Delete row in webgrid with checkboxes in MVC3 using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I am new to MVC3. I have coded an application in which I display data into a webgrid with checkboxes. I am trying to find out how to send a particular row id the controller action method when I click on a checkbox. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on what you are trying to do.  Typically, in the view, I will add a data attribute like data-rowid="###" and then use jQuery to capture the .click event.  Then in the .click event, retrieve the clicked elements value for data-rowid and call .ajax to post the data to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete example where I have a WebGrid with the last column containing a "Remove" link that uses Ajax to call an action on the server. On completion of the Ajax request, the corresponding row is removed from the table. The `MvcHtmlString` is used to inject a span tag into the column. It contains an id value that is subsequently used to identify the row to be removed from the table.

```
<div id="ssGrid">
    @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: false, canSort: false);
        grid.Bind(
            source: Model,
            columnNames: new[] { "Location", "Number", "Protection", "Methodology" }
        );
    }
    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webGrid",
        headerStyle: "header",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Location", "Location"),
            grid.Column("Number", "Number"),
            grid.Column("Protection", "Protection"),
            grid.Column("Methodology", "Methodology"),
            grid.Column(
                format: (item) => 
                    new MvcHtmlString(string.Format("<span id='ssGrid{0}'>{1}</span>",
                                          item.SecondarySystemId,
                                          @Ajax.RouteLink("Remove",
                                              "Detail", // route name
                                              new { action = "RemoveSecondarySystem", actionId = item.SecondarySystemId },
                                              new AjaxOptions { 
                                                  OnComplete = "removeRow('ssGrid" + item.SecondarySystemId + "')"
                                              }
                                          )
                                     )
                    )
            )
        )
    )
</div>

<script>
    function removeRow(rowId) {
        $("#" + rowId).closest("tr").remove();
    }
</script>
```