# Delete webgrid row using javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I have a `webgrid` in mvc3. It has the column `delete`. Upon clicking it, I want to run a Javascript function to redirect the user to a controller's action by passing a row id as the parameter to the Javascript function.

How would I do this? The column is not an `Htmlactionlink`.

Comment: Looks like question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650659/using-javascript-variable-in-asp-net-view-with-webgrid-column][1] is related to above question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650659/using-javascript-variable-in-asp-net-view-with-webgrid-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is the way you have the rows:-

```
<tr id="thisRowId">
  .
  .
  .
 <td>
    <a id="deleteBtn" data-rowId="thisRowId">delete</a>
 </td>
<tr>
```

Have a generic function for your delete click

```
$('#deleteBtn').click(function(){

var id =   $(this).data('rowId'); // or use $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');

$.ajax({
url: "controller/action",
type: 'Delete', // assuming your action is marked with HttpDelete Attribute or do not need this option if action is marked with HttpGet attribute
data: {'id' : "'" + id  "'"} // pass in id here
success : yoursuccessfunction
});

};
```

Answer (score 1):

As documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22548760/132599), this is an example of removing a table row from a `WebGrid` following an AJAX request. `WebGrid` doesn't make it easy to identify a particular item in the table. The issue is how to identify the row to be deleted. In the example, the `MvcHtmlString` is used to inject a span tag into the column. It contains an id value that is subsequently used to identify the row to be removed from the table.

```
<div id="ssGrid">
    @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: false, canSort: false);
        grid.Bind(
            source: Model,
            columnNames: new[] { "Location", "Number" }
        );
    }
    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webGrid",
        headerStyle: "header",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Location", "Location"),
            grid.Column("Number", "Number"),
            grid.Column(
                format: (item) => 
                    new MvcHtmlString(string.Format("<span id='ssGrid{0}'>{1}</span>",
                                          item.SecondarySystemId,
                                          @Ajax.RouteLink("Delete",
                                              "Detail", // route name
                                              new { action = "DeleteSecondarySystem", actionId = item.SecondarySystemId },
                                              new AjaxOptions { 
                                                  OnComplete = "removeRow('ssGrid" + item.SecondarySystemId + "')"
                                              }
                                          )
                                     )
                    )
            )
        )
    )
</div>

<script>
    function removeRow(rowId) {
        $("#" + rowId).closest("tr").remove();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try attaching a jQuery click handler to the element like so:

HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <a id="your id">delete</a>
  </td>
<tr>
```

Javascript:

```
$("tr a").click(function() {
  //your code
});
```